# Jquery I need to apply same function with different characteristics

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need is to apply a jquery function three elements but with different features such as fade in / out, FB.XFBML.parse, etc. I tried to put aside the function does not work and I know I'm doing something wrong, I can you lend a hand?

This is the jQuery code:

```
function load(div, of) {
    $(div).load(of, function() {    
        FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('div-d'));
        twttr.widgets.load();
    }).hide().fadeIn("slow");    
}

$.getScript("jquery.cycle.all.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    console.log(data); // Data returned
    console.log(textStatus); // Success
    console.log(jqxhr.status); // 200
    console.log("Load was performed.");
});

options = $.extend( options || {}, {
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
    url: url
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Reload").click(function() {
        $("#result").html("result reloaded successfully");
    });
});
```

button 1:

```
<a href="#inicio" onClick="load('.div-d','road.php')" class="temas-deco-d">ROAD</a>
```

button 2:

```
<a href="#inicio" onClick="load('.div-d','street.php')" class="temas-deco-d">STREET</a>
```

button3:

```
<a href="#inicio" onClick="load('.div-d','house.php')" class="temas-deco-d">house</a>
```

Button 1 want to load the div without `FB.XFBML.parse`.

Two button want to load the div without the `fade effect`

I want the button three load the script `jquery.cycle.all.js`

**EDIT with code brian:**

script:

```
     function load(div, of)
{
     $(div).load(of, function() {
});  
}
$('.botones-lateral-j').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this) // cache jquery `this` object so we don't need to reinstantiate it every time we use it

    var script = $this.data('script');
    var target = $this.data('target');
    var button = $this.data('button');

    console.log(script, target, button); // log data to make sure it's correct, remove before deployment

    switch (button) {
        case 'lateral':
            $(target).load(of, function() {    
               twttr.widgets.load();
            }).hide().fadeIn("slow"); 
            break;
        case 'button2':
            $(target).load(of, function() {    
               FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('div-d'));
               twttr.widgets.load();
            }).hide();
            break;
        case 'button3':
            $.getScript("jquery.cycle.all.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                console.log(data); // Data returned
                console.log(textStatus); // Success
                console.log(jqxhr.status); // 200
                console.log("Load was performed.");
            });
        break;
    }
});
```

button:

```
<a href="#inicio" class="botones-lateral-j" data-script="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/dis/lateral-2.php" data-target="#lateral" data-button="lateral1">SIG</a>
```

I tried the fade in effect to see if it removes the data-button lateral1
It does not work, not even change the div :(

Comment: Have a parameter where you can specify the button effect type. Then in the function have an switch statement which splits the effect.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I do not have much knowledge about javascript

Comment: Check your syntax.  Missing " " around first div, on getElementById are you trying to access #div-d because i only see you passing in a parameter of class div-d and if you are trying to get the class, just access it using the parameter you passed in

Comment: Posted an answer, done  on mobile will try reformat and updates when I'm on PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - including event listeners and using a `data-*` attribute instead of the script in the switch.

HTML:

```
<a href="#inicio" class="temas-deco-d" data-script="road.php" data-target=".div-d" data-button="button1">ROAD</a>
<a href="#inicio" class="temas-deco-d" data-script="street.php" data-target=".div-d" data-button="button2">STREET</a>
<a href="#inicio" class="temas-deco-d" data-script="house.php" data-target=".div-d" data-button="button3">HOUSE</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.temas-deco-d').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this) // cache jquery `this` object so we don't need to reinstantiate it every time we use it

    var script = $this.data('script');
    var target = $this.data('target');
    var button = $this.data('button');

    console.log(script, target, button); // log data to make sure it's correct, remove before deployment

    switch (button) {
        case 'button1':
            $(target).load(script, function() {    
               twttr.widgets.load();
            }).hide().fadeIn("slow"); 
            break;
        case 'button2':
            $(target).load(script, function() {    
               FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('div-d'));
               twttr.widgets.load();
            }).hide();
            break;
        case 'button3':
            $.getScript("jquery.cycle.all.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                console.log(data); // Data returned
                console.log(textStatus); // Success
                console.log(jqxhr.status); // 200
                console.log("Load was performed.");
            });
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Could it be a class button instead of the file?It is that I make many calls to different files

Comment: I do not work, forgive my ignorance, I put that code below the mine? or I take mine and put this you put me.

Comment: The correct way to do this would be to attach an event listener to `.div-d`, add a `data-*` attribute (`data-button` maybe) and then `var button = $(this).data('button')` and base the switch statement on `button` instead of the script. This way you can use the same `data-button` for multiple scripts. and @pTRONICA - this would replace your `load()` function

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, sorry. Could you edit your answer with the code applied? If it's not too much trouble for you. I know you've given me an answer right but I can not understand until you see it. Thank you

Comment: @pTRONICA updated - I just noticed your `$('#Reload').click()` only updates the html and doesn't actually call your old `load` function. This should replace everything except the `options` you extended.

Comment: I tried but it does not work I do not know where to place each piece of code, forgive me but I do not understand, I find it difficult. :_S

Comment: I will decitar the first message for you to see as I am integrating, to see if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Brian edited the first post so you can see as I am implementing, to see if I'm missing something in the javascript code not loaded with external content div does not work in any way

Comment: @pTRONICA forgot to swap `of` for `script`.

Comment: Sorry Brian for being so silly, but I put error. The load function standing above the onclick event where it would now? because I think that missing

I edit the first post

Comment: The load function in the onclick was replaced by the anonymous function in the jquery event listener. Is the script logging data to the console when you click on `.temas-deco-d`? This is probably as far as I'm gonna be able to take you.

Comment: I have logradoo still I do not know how I did it but it has left me haha. Thank you, thank you so much for everything !!

Could you point me to thank the other guy who has tried to help? 15 need to score, thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

In between the cases put the styling.

```
function load(styleType) {
    switch (styleType) {
        case "button1":

        break;

        case "button2":

        break;

        case "button3":

        break;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to put your own parameters  too.

If you have any issues just post.

Comment: Thank you very much, more or less what I see but I mess to run. Let's see if I can put a complete example when you get home.

Comment: No problem. I thought I'd let you tinker with it, that's why I didn't give the full answer.

Comment: Also don't forget to tick/up-vote answers  which helped. :P

Comment: Hey Script47 you come home now?

Comment: @pTRONICA yes, what's up? I already reformatted the code, you need to add your code between the cases so style for button1 goes between `case "button1:` and the `break` and so on.

Comment: See if you can edit your solution with good assembled code. I have almost no knowledge about js